# sed 's:\\ ::g' doesn't seem to work properly while installing Gazebo

Tags: sed

I'm trying to compile Gazebo on my Ubuntu 17.04.

I'm following this [instructions](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install), but it seems to be an error in the following one:

```
sudo apt-get install $(sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $BASE_DEPENDENCIES) $(sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $GAZEBO_BASE_DEPENDENCIES)
```

I don't understand what is doing here: `sed 's:\\ ::g'`

When I run the previous command `sudo apt-get install ...` I get the following error 42 times:

> E: Unable to locate package \

I have echoed both variables.

```
echo $BASE_DEPENDENCIES
build-essential \ cmake \ debhelper \ mesa-utils \ cppcheck \ xsltproc \ python-psutil \ python \ bc \ netcat-openbsd \ gnupg2 \ net-tools \ locales
```

And the other one:

```
echo $GAZEBO_BASE_DEPENDENCIES
libfreeimage-dev \ libprotoc-dev \ libprotobuf-dev \ protobuf-compiler \ freeglut3-dev \ libcurl4-openssl-dev \ libtinyxml-dev \ libtar-dev \ libtbb-dev \ libogre-1.9-dev \ libxml2-dev \ pkg-config \ qtbase5-dev \ libqwt-qt5-dev \ libltdl-dev \ libgts-dev \ libboost-thread-dev \ libboost-signals-dev \ libboost-system-dev \ libboost-filesystem-dev \ libboost-program-options-dev \ libboost-regex-dev \ libboost-iostreams-dev \ libbullet-dev \ libsimbody-dev \ \ libignition-transport3-dev \ libignition-math3-dev \ libignition-msgs-dev \ libtinyxml2-dev \ libsdformat5-dev
```

The output for the command `sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $BASE_DEPENDENCIES` is:

```
build-essential \
                   cmake           \
                   debhelper       \
                   mesa-utils      \
                   cppcheck        \
                   xsltproc        \
                   python-psutil   \
                   python          \
                   bc              \
                   netcat-openbsd  \
                   gnupg2          \
                   net-tools       \
                   locales
```

**UPDATE**
I have tried the command `sed 's:\\[[:space:]]::g' <<< $BASE_DEPENDENCIES` with the following output:

```
user@Mpc:~$ sed 's:\\[[:space:]]::g' <<< $BASE_DEPENDENCIES
build-essential \
                   cmake           \
                   debhelper       \
                   mesa-utils      \
                   cppcheck        \
                   xsltproc        \
                   python-psutil   \
                   python          \
                   bc              \
                   netcat-openbsd  \
                   gnupg2          \
                   net-tools       \
                   locales
```

**UPDATE 2**
It seems that the sed command is ok. If I do the following, without using the env variable I get the right string:

```
user@pc:~$ echo 'build-essential \ cmake \ debhelper \ mesa-utils \ cppcheck \ xsltproc \ python-psutil \ python \ bc \ netcat-openbsd \ gnupg2 \ net-tools \ locales' | sed 's:\\ ::g'
build-essential cmake debhelper mesa-utils cppcheck xsltproc python-psutil python bc netcat-openbsd gnupg2 net-tools locales
```

**UPDATE 3**
If I surround the env. vars. and echoed I get the newlines and the spaces. But if I echo them without the quotes I get all in one line.

And if I use sed with the env. var without quotes I get the value of the variable with new lines and spaces.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The `sed` command is supposed to remove all backslashes from the variable contents. Obviously it doesn't work, but at the moment I can't see why. Please give the output of `sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $BASE_DEPENDENCIES`

Comment: The sed statement is taking the output from the variable BASE_DEPENDANCIES and GAZEBO_BASE_DEPENDANCIES and removing the back slashes followed by space (two back slashes to escape the back slash). It seems that there maybe two back slashes together in one of the variables?

Comment: If the value of those variables were assigned properly, you would not need to jump through these hoops.  Where do they get their values from?

Comment: Also, are you sure there is a space after all of the back slashes?

Comment: @Philippos I have updated the question with output you need.

Comment: Please take a look to **Update 3**. There is something strange with variable surrounded with quotes.

Comment: The backslashes are at end of lines so you need `sed 's:\\$::'`

Comment: Really, I would say it's the source script at https://bitbucket.org/osrf/release-tools/raw/default/jenkins-scripts/lib/dependencies_archive.sh that should be fixed; introducing backslashes in between package names just to get rid of them later looks quite weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` command is supposed to remove all backslashes from the variable contents, but it expects the backslashes to be followed by spaces. But it seems they are followed by newlines, so use

```
sed -z 's:\\[[:space:]]::g'
```

instead (this is for GNU `sed`, only, but since you are on Ubuntu ...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get the same error.

Comment: Did you replace both? Then please post the output for the changed command.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of your command.

Comment: You are right, The backslashes are followed by newlines. I don't understand why you use `[[:space:]]` instead of newline.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the `-z` option to process all lines in the same buffer. Without that, each lines is processed alone and doesn't contain newlines of course.